# Response tab UI seems broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments, profile-page

While checking the *Responses* tab in the User Profile section, it seems broken.

Browser: Firefox

[image]

Comment: Related/Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342171/line-word-wrapping-in-revision-history-and-responses-tab-and-probably-other-pla

Comment: I can reproduce this on Meta (Firefox, macOS) but not on main, oddly.

Comment: Confirmed on main with Firefox 72.0.1 and Chromium 79.0.3945.117 on Windows 10.

Comment: Same on Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130 / Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a fix for this in the queue for deployment, but this being Friday night, it probably won't happen till Monday.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Well, I'm glad to see the lesson has been learned about shipping on a Friday. :-) Have a great weekend, Adam!

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed. You too!

Comment: @AdamLear Checked and confirmed! Thanks!