# ev 2020.1.21.35842 layout bug

Tags: bug, design

On my activity page, the columns are too narrow for the date and user:

[image]

The width of the browser window makes no difference.

[Oh, tragedy, the freehand red circle was too narrow to encompass both columns.]

Comment: Cross site dupe: [Line/word wrapping in revision history and responses tab (and probably other places)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342171/232439)

Comment: @scohe001 Has the problem only been added to SO today?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that MSE link shows it happening on Aviation a week ago, so I'd think it'd be across the whole network.

Comment: That could be fitting, with a new coronavirus spreading through aviation passengers. Let's hope it's brought under control soon.

Comment: Heh. Also after a little more searching, it seems this *was* actually brought up on MSO a few days ago: [Response tab UI seems broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392925/response-tab-ui-seems-broken)

Comment: I guess I should blame caching for not seeing it sooner. *Six days* without a fix so far; maybe they haven't seen the posts reporting it yet and another one will make it more visible.